# Why to say, my function is of IFly type rather than saying it's Airplane type

Tags: object-oriented, programming-practices, interfaces

Say, I have two classes:

Airplane and Bird, both of them fly. Both implement the interface IFly. IFly declares a function `StartFlying()`. Thus both Airplane and Bird have to define the function, and use it as per their requirement.

Now when I make a manual for class reference, what should I write for the function `StartFlying`?

1) `StartFlying` is a function of type IFly .

2) `StartFlying` is a function of type Airplane

3) `StartFlying` is a function of type Bird.

My opinion is 2 and 3 are more informative. But what i see is that class references use the 1st one. They say what interface the function is declared in. Problem is, I really don't get any usable information from knowing `StartFlying` is IFly type. However, knowing that `StartFlying` is a function inside Airplane and Bird, is more informative, as I can decide which instance (Airplane or Bird ) to use.

Any lights on this: how saying `StartFlying` is a function of type IFly, can help a programmer understanding how to use the function?

Comment: What happens if there are lots of classes that implement IFly?  Are you going to list them all each time?  It can be easier to note where the function is declared and look at what classes implement this interface to find which classes may be useful as there may be lots of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from the fact that you named your interface `IFly`. Any recent programming book recommends to **not** name your interfaces with **I** in front. Give your interface a proper name.

In your particular example it would be a little bit harder to do this, but let's take this situation:

- Interface is: `FlyingObject`
- Implementation1: `Airplane implements FlyingObject`
- Implementation2: `Helicopter implements FlyingObject`
- Implementation3: `UFO implements FlyingObject`

If you do this and you try to write a documentation for it, it will be quite clear what `StartFlying on FlyingObject` means.

In some extreme cases, when it's impossible to find the proper abstraction, you may name your interface with a concrete name like `Foo` and than the implementation `FooImplementation` or `FooImpl`.

**UPDATE:** Of course it always depends on what you are documenting and how. If you document your business logic, you can simply say that any `FlyingObject` has a `startFlying()` method. Your business logic will not create those objects, so you don't care what are they exactly. In fact, this makes things much more clearer once you document that your business logic can use any object that has the `startFlying()` method and you connect that knowledge to the interface. You don't care who creates the `Airplane` or `Helicopter`. All you know and document from the point of view of the business logic is that you can start flying if you have an object capable doing so.

On the other hand if you document your factories or whatever logic you have that decides what type of flying object to create, there you can document something like 'Airplane, Helicopter, etc. must implement FlyingObject, otherwise they can't take you to Japan'.

I hope this update clarifies all the question you were asking.

Comment: "Any recent programming book recommends to not name your interfaces with I in front.": what is the motivation for this recommendation?

Comment: And that's why all of the interfaces in the .Net library start with I, Just as many other big projects which use this convention. I think you've got it wrong. That is, unless camelCasing also has been deprecated recently....

The comment on the documentation of code is good, but there are conventions to be followed if we want to be able to understand which things are interfaces and which things are classes without diving into the sources.

Comment: @Giorgio - the motivation is that the interface is the place where the abstract concept of your logic is contained. So, naming it accordingly makes not only the code more readable and natural but also easier to remember. And than, there is the fact that interfaces belong to their clients and **not** to their implementations. You will have, somewhere in your code, a method / object / module using a `FlyingObject` (instead of a `IFly`). However that module will not know or care that what it gets is an `Aitplane` or a `Helicopter`. It will only care about the fact that it can fly.

Comment: PS: And you can compile and deploy your business logic against the interfaces, without the real implementations which may or may not be available at compile time or desired to be recompiled each time.

Comment: @Onno - I appreciate your sarcasm. CamelCase was not yet deprecated, however Hungarian Notation **was deprecated**. I will respond with the same sarcasm: Read a few recently written (2003+) books and we will talk after that.

Comment: @PatkosCsaba well, the [Microsoft guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229040%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  for C#  say explicitly: - *"Do not give class names a prefix (such as the letter C).
Interfaces, which should begin with the letter I, are the exception to this rule."* No prefix in Java though :)

Comment: Actually, to clear again, what i am asking is: Let's say i provide you a class reference with an information say: you can use function printThisPage() which is of type IVishwasInterface. Now in this case how to know, which Class's instance should i instantiate to use function printThisPage() ??? Obviously i cannot instantiate IVishwasInterface.

Comment: See updated answer, hope it explains all your questions.

Comment: -1 for the first paragraph, since it applies only to some languages, but you never mention it. In C# for example, starting a name of an interface with I is mandatory.

Comment: @MainMa It's not mandatory, only recommended. There's nothing in the C# language specification that requires interface names to be prefixed with the letter 'I', but it is a recommended practice.

Comment: @pmarflee: in C# language, nothing. But it's still mandatory if you must match Microsoft guidelines or if your code must be StyleCop compliant.

Comment: @MainMa: and still, Robert C. Marting in his Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices **in C#** recommends as I said above.

Comment: @Patkos IIRC, Robert Martin only recommends using Hungarian Notation for interfaces because it's such an established idiom in the .NET community, not because there's a particularly good reason for doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Say `StartFlying()` is a method/function in `IFly`. The documentation should include:

- How to find IFly, such as the namespace (.net or Java)/header file (e.g. C++) and file (such as an assembly in .Net or JAR file in Java).
- Specify what the caller needs to supply, such as arguments to the method and their allowable values,
- What the implementer needs to do, such as changes to other properties or return values.
- Error handling, such as what exceptions thrown and under what conditions.
- Security requirements. For example, does the user need to be a member of the `Pilots` group?
- Links to similar interfaces (e.g. `IWalk`, `IRun`)
- Link to an example or overview

You may want to include links or references to classes that implement `IFly`, such as `Bird` and `Aeroplane` but this may be manual and, therefore, prone to omissions or copy and paste errors.

Why describe `StartFlying()` in IFly in than `Bird` or `Aeroplane`? `StartFlying()` has been abstracted into an interface to standardize access similar functionality across disparate classes. This means other classes may implement it in the future beyond `Bird` and `Aeroplane`, both inside your library and outside.

Reference the documentation for `IFly` in the documentation for `Bird` and `Aeroplane` as well but these should also include implementation specific details. `Aeroplane`, for example, may require `IsFueled()` to be true, and including this in `IFly` would be confusing.